# Defining predicates in SICStus Prolog / SWI-Prolog REPL

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel, prolog-assert

I am reading http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node3.html#subsec.l1.kb1,
but I am having trouble running the following predicate:

```
SICStus 4.0.1 (x86-win32-nt-4): Tue May 15 21:17:49 WEST 2007
| ?- woman(mia).
! Existence error in user:woman/1
! procedure user:woman/1 does not exist
! goal:  user:woman(mia)
| ?-
```

If, on the other hand, I write it to a file and run consult the file, it seems to work fine...

Am I only allowed to define predicates in a file having later to consult them? Can't I just do it in the editor itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should enter `woman(mia).` into a file to assert it as a fact. If you write it into the interpreter, it's taken as a query, not a fact.

From the [SWI Prolog FAQ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt):

> Terms that you enter at the toplevel are processes as queries, while
>   terms that appear in a file that is loaded into Prolog is processed as
>   a set of rules and facts. If a text reads as below, this is a rule.
>
> ```
> carnivore(X) :- animal(X), eats_meat(X).
> ```
>
> Trying to enter this at the toplevel results in the error below. Why?
>   Because a rule is a term :-(Head, Body), and because the toplevel
>   interprets terms as queries. There is no predicate with the name :-
>   and two arguments.
>
> ```
> ?- carnivore(X) :- animal(X), eats_meat(X). ERROR: Undefined
> procedure: (:-)/2 ERROR:   Rules must be loaded from a file ERROR:  
> See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
> ```
>
> Isn't this stupid? Well, no. Suppose we have a term
>   eats_meat(rataplan). If this appears in a file, it states the fact
>   that rataplan eats meat. If it appears at the toplevel, it asks Prolog
>   to try proving whether rataplan eats meat.
>
> If a text reads
>
> ```
> :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
> ```
>
> This is a directive. Directives are similar to queries, but instead of
>   asking the toplevel to do something, they ask the compiler to do
>   something. Like rules and facts, such terms belong in files.

Instead of writing to a file you can also use `assert` in the toplevel (as explained later in the FAQ as well).

Comment: So, in this case *assert(woman(mia))*. would do just what I want?

Comment: The error message can be missleading for a novice. Since rules can also be loaded from user, which is not exactly a file. But this is a general problem of creating good error messages.

Answer (score 12):

It's a little annoying to make predicates in the repl. You could do

```
| ?- ['user'].
woman(mia).
^D
```

ie consult user input, or

```
| ?- assertz(woman(mia)).
```

assert it. Both awkward IMO -- there might be a better way, though, I just don't know it. In general it is easier to use a script.